# WebMethod with unknown params

Tags: c#, web-services

I have C# WebService with the following WebMethod:

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "GET", UriTemplate = "/MyWebMethod?param1={param1}", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
void MyWebMethod(string param1);
```

Example request:
http://localhost/MyWebMethod?param1=1

I'm trying to create `WebMethod` with unknown param number like the following:

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "GET", UriTemplate = "/MyWebMethod?[WHAT I NEED TO WRITE HERE?]", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
void MyWebMethod(KeyValuePair<string, string> params);
```

What I need to replace instead of **[WHAT I NEED TO WRITE HERE?]** to get unknown parameters?

Example request:
http://localhost/MyWebMethod?param1=1&param2=2&x=3&y=4

How can I do that?

Comment: I've never done this, but according to the documentation, `UriTemplate` accepts a `/*`. So try something like `MyWebMethod/*` and then use the `Uri` class within your method to extract the query string parameters instead of taking them as arguments to the method.

Comment: @Crowcoder, Thanks but its not worked for me..